# how to draw a imageUrl in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using html5 `canvas` with `SignalR`.
I got the canvas Url By this,

```
var refreshCanvas = canvasParent.toDataURL();
whiteBoard.server.refreshCanvas(refreshCanvas);
```

I am getting data on client-side also, as a url string by:

```
whiteBoard.client.refreshCanvas = function (refreshCanvas){
    //alert(refreshCanvas);
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function () {
        contextParent.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = refreshCanvas;
}
```

I have checked that imagedata Url is coming as string but my problem is how to draw that imageUrl data onto my canvas.

my canvas name is "canvasParent" and context name is "contextParent".

I am getting image Url As :

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABOIAAAIDCAYAAACpTrFbAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3YMQ0AAAgEMfBvGhXcVAx80jDdjiNAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBA4F1g3xcMECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECAwQpwnIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBKVZdR4AABBjSURBVAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAICHEBsgkCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECQpwfIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAIHNVNAgShTDHtAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Comment: That is not a URL. That is the binary representation of an image

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879641/displaying-images-in-html5-canvas-from-binary-data

Comment: img.src = dataURL; Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976327/binary-array-to-canvas

Comment: then what should i do to print that binary representation of an image into a canvas.  @ jasonscript

Comment: img.src = dataURL;   is not helping  @Joep

Comment: What did you do? Only img.src = dataURL; won't work off coarse, you need some extra code to specify dataURL. Did you check the link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas

Comment: whiteBoard.client.refreshCanvas = function (refreshCanvas)
            {
                var img = new Image;
                img.onload = function () {
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // Or at whatever offset you like
                };
                img.src = refreshCanvas;
           }

Comment: I simply want to show that imageUrl data in the canvas .,but that is not working. i am  getting urldata on refreshCanvas .@jeop

Comment: So you are actually taking a snapshot of the canvas to draw it back to itself ? Why ? Ps: you are calling `whiteBoard.server.refreshCanvas();` but defined `whiteBoard.client.refreshCanvas();` maybe this is the issue.

Comment: No I am working On signalR ,so whiteBoard.server.refreshCanvas(); and whiteBoard.client.refreshCanvas(); both are correct..@Kalido

Comment: Ok I don't know signalR nor ASP.net btw, but I assume that `contextParent` is `canvasParent`'s context. So you are actually drawing one canvas to itself. Also, if you are only defining `whiteBoard.client.refreshCanvas`, it seems really strange that `whiteBoard.server.refreshCanvas` got updated too. Except if `whiteBoard.client` and `whiteBoard.server` are actually two instances of the same object.